# How to merge multiple PDFs on the client side

Tags: javascript, pdf, client-side

Is it possible to merge multiple PDFs into one through just the client alone? http://mrrio.github.io/jsPDF/# looked like an answer but it doesn't seem to have the feature of merging two already made pdfs.

Is something like this possible?

Comment: Is there a reason there isn't an already made solution of this? Wouldn't it imply there's a difficult reason why you can't?

Comment: No, there is no reason why you can't. It's just not particularly useful and Javascript has not been very efficient up until recently. This is not an easy coding job though, you'd have to learn PDF specification. Why don't you just display one PDF, then display the next immediately after and make it look to the user like it's only one?

Comment: The file is required to be portable to another computer and for ease of use it would be to cumbersome for the user if it isn't one big file.

Comment: Well it's a big job to write the whole thing in Javascript. But PDFTK would do it server-side in a split-second.